# Django model not saving to database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Ok, a project that a small team I am working on is new to django and developing a webapp, when all of a sudden we lost all ability to add a model object into the database. We are all at a complete loss. Below is where we are in debugging currently.

views.py

```
def postOp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        operation = request.POST.get("operation","noop")

        #Registered user operations
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            username = request.session.get("member","Guest")
            user = ToolUser.objects.get(name=username)
            zipcode = user.location
            .
            .
            #AddTool
            if operation == "addTool":
               toolName = request.POST.get("toolName","N/A")
               toolDesc = request.POST.get("toolDesc","N/A")
               print("In addtools")
               user.submitTool(toolName, toolDesc)
               print("SUBITTED")
               return HttpResponseRedirect("tools")
```

model

```
def submitTool(self, Nname, Ndescription):
        print("IN SUBMIT ")
        t = Tool(name=Nname, owner=self.id, shed=self.id, description=Ndescription, currOwner=0, location=self.location)
    print("tool made :", t.name, ", ", t.owner, ", ", t.shed, ", ", t.description, \
                      ", ",t.currOwner ,", ", t.location)
    t.save()
    print("saving tool")
```

It appears that it gets all the way to the t.save(), then breaks. using a seperate tool to view the database, it is clearly not getting saved to the table. BUT with the following output to the terminal, it does appear to be creating this instance.

terminal output:

In addtools

IN SUBMIT

tool made : tooltest ,  2 ,  2 ,  description ,  0 ,  12345

EDIT: forgot to update this, found the problem, turns out one field was empty, and django refuses to save something that has empty fields.

Comment: In a REPL, are you able to create new objects? `python manage.py shell`, create an object then try to save it. You will probably get a more verbose response such as an exception traceback.

Comment: And what about other Model in your project? Only Tool goes wrong or all models go wrong? If former, may check definition of Tool; the latter, check settings of DB

Comment: ZZY - I can register users and add other models to their respective tables without any problem.

Comment: Sebleblanc - I've been having problems with the python command in my cmd prompt so i can't actully do "python manage.py (anything)". I have been running the commands though eclipse but I can't get an interactive shell. I get this when trying " 'module' object has no attribute 'setup_environ'  "

Comment: What do you mean, it "breaks"? Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Well thats the thing I get no error, it silently fails, so I'm not sure where to even look at this point. If it can make the object why can't it save it?

Answer (score -1):

So wait, you have a model function called `saveTool()` but you're calling `user.savetool` (which I presume is `django.contrib.auth.user`)? If you say that resolves, then fine.

It's probably better to just populate the object in the `postOp()` function and save it there. If `saveTool()` were indeed part of the model class you'd be instantiating a model object, and then calling a method to instantiate another function.

My point is that from a style perspective, the code is needlessly complex, or this requires more data to really work out what's happening there.

Comment: I do understand where your coming from, and we were through into this project with no instruction on how django actually even works so its a little rough around the edges. Also just to try, populating and saving in the view function doesn't change what is happening. Also that user object is a model we wrote(ToolUser) not the auth user.

Comment: No worries - sorry for taking so long to get back to this. If you're still having issues, set up django's logging infrastructure (try logging on `django.model.*`) to see where the issue might be.